# Blocking keystrokes without low-level hooks?

Tags: c#

How can I block keystrokes without using low-level hooks? I want them entirely blocked from the system, so that they are not being passed to any application at all.

Comment: Why use code when this can be trivially accomplished by hand?  Unplug the keyboard.

Comment: Hans, I want to block specific keystrokes. Not all of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. You need hooks on OS layer for that.